# substr in dplyr %>% mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

```
pcd <- data.frame(tripNo = c(618, 618, 610, 610, 610, 619), 
              procDate = as.Date(c('2016-03-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-03-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-03-02', '2016-03-03')),
              delay = c(7.45, 12.90, 11.88, 6.66, 12.50, 9.41) )
```

I want to flag inconsistencies in trips processed on two different days where the delay for the second day is shorter than the last one on the previous day. I have now done it this way:

```
pcd %>%
  arrange(tripNo, procDate, delay) %>% 
  group_by(tripNo) %>% 
  mutate(delayErr = (row_number() != 1) & (delay < lag(delay)),
         Alert = ifelse(delayErr, '!', '')) %>%
  select(tripNo, procDate, delay, delayErr, Alert)

  tripNo   procDate delay delayErr Alert
   (dbl)     (date) (dbl)    (lgl) (chr)
1    610 2016-03-02 11.88    FALSE      
2    610 2016-03-02 12.50    FALSE      
3    610 2016-03-03  6.66     TRUE     !
4    618 2016-03-02  7.45    FALSE      
5    618 2016-03-03 12.90    FALSE      
6    619 2016-03-03  9.41    FALSE
```

So this works OK, my question is about my first attempt, in which I tried to use substr:

```
pcd %>% arrange(tripNo, procDate, delay) %>% 
group_by(tripNo) %>% 
mutate(delayErr = (row_number() != 1) & (delay < lag(delay)),
       Alert = substr(' !', delayErr + 1, delayErr + 1) ) %>%  # <<< This is the only change
select(tripNo, procDate, delay, delayErr, Alert)

  tripNo   procDate delay delayErr Alert
   (dbl)     (date) (dbl)    (lgl) (chr)
1    610 2016-03-02 11.88    FALSE      
2    610 2016-03-02 12.50    FALSE      
3    610 2016-03-03  6.66     TRUE      
4    618 2016-03-02  7.45    FALSE      
5    618 2016-03-03 12.90    FALSE      
6    619 2016-03-03  9.41    FALSE
```

With this code, the Alert does not show as I expected.
Could someone explain to me why the second dplyr query doesn't work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a vectorized version of `substr` i.e. `substring`

```
pcd %>%
  arrange(tripNo, procDate, delay) %>% 
  group_by(tripNo) %>% 
  mutate(delayErr = (row_number() != 1) & (delay < lag(delay)),
         Alert = substring(' !', delayErr +1, delayErr +1)) %>% 
  select(tripNo, procDate, delay, delayErr, Alert)
#   tripNo   procDate delay delayErr Alert
#   (dbl)     (date) (dbl)    (lgl) (chr)
#1    610 2016-03-02 11.88    FALSE      
#2    610 2016-03-02 12.50    FALSE      
#3    610 2016-03-03  6.66     TRUE     !
#4    618 2016-03-02  7.45    FALSE      
#5    618 2016-03-03 12.90    FALSE      
#6    619 2016-03-03  9.41    FALSE
```

Comment: Pls excuse my lack of understanding: your answer works perfectly of course, but in the context of a dplyr call, why is delayErr a vector? Isn't substr called with just the value of the current row?

Comment: @ap53 Each column in the data.frame is a `vector`.  I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Why is there no difference between these two columns?

Comment: @ap53 Which columns?

Comment: Excuse me, just having problems with the editor and pasting code...  I will start a new question

Answer (score 1):

It's because `substr` expects single values as second and third arguments, but you are providing numeric vectors. You could make a vectorized version of substr with

```
substr2 <- Vectorize(substr)
```

If you then replace your original function with this new function it should work as expected.

Comment: Isn't `Vectorize(substr)` just `substring()`?