# dplyr: vectorisation of substr

Tags: r, dplyr

Referring to question [substr in dplyr %>% mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676502/substr-in-dplyr-mutate/36676935#36676935), and to @akrun 's answer, why do the two created columns give the same answer?

```
df <- data_frame(t = '1234567890ABCDEFG', a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
df %>%  mutate(u = substr(t, a,  a + b), v = substring(t, a,  a + b))
```

I can't grasp the difference with the situation in the original question.
Thank you!

Comment: Write your full question here instead of expecting us to follow links, please.

Comment: When you already have a column created, both `substr` and `substring` create the same output.  Based on your previous question, check `pcd %>%arrange(tripNo, procDate, delay)%>% group_by(tripNo) %>% mutate(delayErr = (row_number() != 1) & (delay < lag(delay)), Sub = " !", Alert = substr(Sub, delayErr + 1, delayErr + 1))`  If you are using `substr(" !", delayErr + 1, delayErr + 1)`, I think it gets evaluated only for the first row as it is not vectorized.

Comment: You can also check with the example here `df %>% mutate(u = substr("1234567890ABCDEFG", a, a+b), v = substring("1234567890ABCDEFG", a, a+b))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you! I understand now. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Frank I'm sorry, I got stuck with the SO editor in the middle of akrun's explanation and the best I could find was to start a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the vectorization

```
substr("1234567890ABCDEFG", df$a, df$a+df$b)
#[1] "1234567"
substring("1234567890ABCDEFG", df$a, df$a+df$b)
#[1] "1234567"     "23456789"    "34567890A"   "4567890ABC"  "567890ABCDE"
```

The `substr` returns only a single value while the `substring` returns a `vector` of `length` equal to the number of rows in the dataset 'df'.  As there is only a single value output, it gets recycled in the `mutate`.  However, if we are using multiple values i.e.

```
substr(rep("1234567890ABCDEFG", nrow(df)), df$a, df$a+df$b)
#[1] "1234567"     "23456789"    "34567890A"   "4567890ABC"  "567890ABCDE"
substring(rep("1234567890ABCDEFG", nrow(df)), df$a, df$a+df$b)
#[1] "1234567"     "23456789"    "34567890A"   "4567890ABC"  "567890ABCDE"
```

Then, the output is the same.  In the OP's example, it gets the above output as the `x` in `substr` has the same length as `start` and `stop`.  We can replicate the first output with

```
 df %>%
     mutate(u = substr("1234567890ABCDEFG", a, a+b),
            v = substring("1234567890ABCDEFG", a, a+b)) 
#                 t     a     b       u           v
#              (chr) (int) (int)   (chr)       (chr)
#1 1234567890ABCDEFG     1     6 1234567     1234567
#2 1234567890ABCDEFG     2     7 1234567    23456789
#3 1234567890ABCDEFG     3     8 1234567   34567890A
#4 1234567890ABCDEFG     4     9 1234567  4567890ABC
#5 1234567890ABCDEFG     5    10 1234567 567890ABCDE
```